# Crypto.js error encryption in winjs

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, winjs

I am trying implement AES 128 encryption between WinJS javascript and PHP. I am using Crypto.js in winJS for the encryption.

Here is my encryption code:

```
var options = { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 };

/*** encrypt */
var encryptDATA= CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("2.0", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", options);
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(json.ciphertext);

/*** decrypt */
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", options);
var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

I get the right answer when I encrypt encryptDATA, but I get a wrong answer when I try to encrypt `ciphertext`. Why is this happening?

Comment: How to get HARDWARE ID in winjs?

Comment: What exactly is json.ciphertext in? Is it a CryptoJS Word?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Base64.stringify` , you need to use `Base64.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that your `json.ciphertext` value that's being passed to the `Base64.stringify()` function is not an instance of `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray`, which it needs to be for the Base64 encoding to function appropriately.

I've set up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Hyfd/ to demonstrate encrypting a string using that functionality and pasted the relevant code below:

```
/*** encrypt base64 encoded */
var words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("2.0"); 
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(words);
var encryptDATA = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(ciphertext, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", options);

/*** decrypt base64 encoded */
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptDATA, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", options);
var plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);
plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(plaintext).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Note this may not be the most efficient way to solve your problem, but it does correctly decrypt the data from the way you are attempting to currently.